# Ecore Concrete Syntax validation failed

Tags: xtext, emf, ecore

I am getting this error message when trying to use my Editor, which i generated from a ecore model:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Concrete Syntax validation failed
The feature ... contains non-transient values but has no corresponding assignment in rule ...

Interestingly, when googling this i am getting no hits for the exact error message:
https://www.google.de/search?q=Concrete+Syntax+validation+failed&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=G_SaVbyuGIXmUoqunKAG#safe=off&q=%22Concrete+Syntax+validation+failed%22

Has anybody ever encountered this error before?

Comment: it says: you have a thing in your model you try to serialize but no rule in the grammar on how to serialize

Comment: Thank you, this will give me something to go on :-)